pixel values by rasterio.transform.rowcol
I am trying to extract pixel values from the raster using the pixel coordinates. The following is part of my code. The pixel value I get is far different from the value I get from the same pixel when I use qgis
`
   with rasterio.open(im_list[im]) as src: meta=src.meta
        rowcol = rasterio.transform.rowcol(meta['transform'], xs=lon, ys=lat)        

        w = src.read(1, window=Window(rowcol[0], rowcol[1], 1, 1))

printing rowcol gives (60877, 52170)
I used rasterio.transform.xy(meta['transform'], 60877, 52170) to figure out whether I get the same coordinates.
The resulting coordinates were slightly different.
In summary, I need to get the same value I obtain in QGIS.

What have you tried so far?
